# Creating custom listview from pre-existing arraylist

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I'm obviously missing something in making this custom adapter. Basically, I've got code that grabs JSON from the site, then breaks it down into a ArrayList. I can do a .toString() and spit it all out onto a listview just fine, but everything I find on the net for creating a custom adapter creates the list inside of it. Is there a way to just supply your pre-created list? I've yet to make any headway on getting the custom one to work...but, as I said I can get the string to work just fine, so I'll include that code.

Here's my classes:

```
public class JSONEvents {
String eid;
String bid;
private String bname;
private String valid;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Events [eid=" + eid + ", bid=" + bid + ", bname=" + bname
            + ", start=" + start + ", end=" + end + ", points=" + points
            + ", title=" + title + ", description=" + description
            + ", cat=" + cat + ", type=" + type + ", subtype=" + subtype
            + ", valid=" + valid + "]";
}
public String getEventInfo(String field){
    if("eid".equals(field)){return eid;}
    else if("bid".equals(field)){return bid;}
    else if("bname".equals(field)){return bname;}
    else if("valid".equals(field)){return valid;}
    return "none";

}
}

public class JSONAdventures {
private String aid;
private String bid;
private String start;
private String valid;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Adventures [aid=" + aid + ", bid=" + bid + ", start=" + start
            + ", end=" + end + ", points=" + points + ", title=" + title
            + ", description=" + description + ", cat=" + cat + ", type="
            + type + ", subtype=" + subtype + ", steps_comp=" + steps_comp
            + ", total_steps=" + total_steps + ", valid=" + valid + "]";
}
public String getEventInfo(String field){
    if("aid".equals(field)){return aid;}
    else if("bid".equals(field)){return bid;}
    else if("start".equals(field)){return start;}
    else if("valid".equals(field)){return valid;}
    return "none";

}

}
public class JSONEandA {
private ArrayList<JSONEvents> events;
private ArrayList<JSONAdventures> adventures;
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ResponseHolder [events=" + events + ", adventures="
                + adventures + "]";
}
public ArrayList<JSONEvents> getJSONEvents() {
    return events;
}
public ArrayList<JSONAdventures> getJSONAdventures() {
    return adventures;
}

}
```

For the code in m activity:

```
List<JSONEvents> eventlist = new ArrayList<JSONEvents>();
try {
    Gson googleJson = new Gson();
    JSONEandA rh = googleJson.fromJson(example,
                   JSONEandA.class);
    for (JSONEvents e : rh.getJSONEvents()) {
         eventlist.add(e);
         //eventlist.addAll(e);

         // System.out.println(e.toString());
         System.out.println(e.getEventInfo("eid"));
         System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.eventlistview);
    String[] values = new String[eventlist.size()];
    eventlist.toArray(values);

    // String[] values = new String[] {e.toString()};
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        list.add(values[i]);
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(
    Events.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
    final View view, int position, long id) {
    final String item = (String) parent
        .getItemAtPosition(position);
    list.remove(item);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Item Removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 });
```

I've also pieced together an attempt at an adapter from various tutorials and such, but can't figure out how to tie it all together:

```
class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONEvents> {

private ArrayList<JSONEvents> items;

public EventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<JSONEvents> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_events, null);
    }
    JSONEvents q = items.get(position);
    if (q != null) {
        TextView nameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstline);
        TextView priceText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

        if (nameText != null) {
            nameText.setText(q.getEventInfo("eid"));
        }
        if (priceText != null) {
            priceText.setText(q.getEventInfo("bid"));
        }
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: What is the problem really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put tha data into your adapter?

```
adapter.addAll(String[] data);
```

Or you could do it while creating adapter:

```
EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, R.id.some_id, eventlist);
```

Comment: That's what it was, I was screwing up the adapter call. Thanks! Got rid of all the extra string code, then changed the eventlist to be ArrayList rather than list, and this worked `final EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(Events.this, R.layout.list_events, eventlist);`